# redefinition error C2086 when trying to declare and define a variable in a namespace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I get the error C2086 from Visual Studio when trying to declare a variable in a name space, define it in one code file and access it in another code file.
When building with gcc (from codeblocks), the error is 
(... == path on my harddisk):

...file_one.cpp|2|error: redefinition of 'RecvVarProxyFn Skins::fnSequenceProxyFn'
...file_one.h|4|note: 'RecvVarProxyFn Skins::fnSequenceProxyFn' previously declared here

Even when deactivating (using `//`) the access line in main(), the error is the same.

file_one.h:

```
typedef int RecvVarProxyFn;

namespace Skins {
    RecvVarProxyFn fnSequenceProxyFn; // "previously declared here"
}
```

file_one.cpp

```
#include "file_one.h"
RecvVarProxyFn Skins::fnSequenceProxyFn = 0; // redefinition error 2086
```

main.cpp

```
#include "file_one.h"
int main()
{   Skins::fnSequenceProxyFn = 1; // making this a comment does not help
    return 0;
}
```

Why do I get a redefinition error for my attempt to define the variable in a separate code file?

NOTE:
I am using visual studio 2015 Target Platform set to version `8.1`
and Platform toolset set to `v140`.

Comment: I think if you specify the type before the member, compiler consider that as a new declaration

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between defining a variable and declaring it? Did you play with using `extern` in one place or another?

Comment: @Yunnosch I didnt. Honestly, i forgot about the extern keyword.

Comment: Adding `extern` in header file helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keyword `extern` to change one of the definitions into a declaration.
Obviously the line in the header is the first choice.

```
namespace Skins {
    extern RecvVarProxyFn fnSequenceProxyFn;
}
```